# Keep only rows repeated more than four times in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency

I have would like to keep only rows repeated more than four times in a pandas dataframe column. Below is a sample dataframe and the desired output. Can anyone please help me with this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Current dataframe

```
Shop     Name     Number
Nike     Tom      45
Nike     Keith    245
Nike     Justin   876
Nike     Thomas   65
Nike     George   06
Adidas   Tom      34
Adidas   Thomas   652
Adidas   Jennifer 872
Apple    Louise   79
Apple    Matthiew 1
Apple    Vincent  652
Apple    George   85
United   Tom      62
United   Benjamin 4
United   James    23
United   Avery    96
United   Marcus   763
United   Justin   45
```

I would look at 'Shop' column and keep those that appeared more than four times, namely Nike and United. My dataframe is very big and contains more comprehensive names than these sample brand names.

Desired output

```
Shop     Name     Number
Nike     Tom      45
Nike     Keith    245
Nike     Justin   876
Nike     Thomas   65
Nike     George   06
United   Tom      62
United   Benjamin 4
United   James    23
United   Avery    96
United   Marcus   763
United   Justin   45
```

Comment: You may also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918506/pandas-how-to-filter-for-items-that-occur-more-than-once-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) filtered by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Shop'].map(df['Shop'].value_counts()).gt(4)]
```

Or solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby('Shop')['Shop'].transform('size').gt(4)]
```

---

```
print (df)
      Shop      Name  Number
0     Nike       Tom      45
1     Nike     Keith     245
2     Nike    Justin     876
3     Nike    Thomas      65
4     Nike    George       6
12  United       Tom      62
13  United  Benjamin       4
14  United     James      23
15  United     Avery      96
16  United    Marcus     763
17  United    Justin      45
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution helped me solved this. Really appreciate your help!