# How to filter out pandas DF, and create 3 new DFs based on those conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a large DF with the following structure:

```
name;id;value;source;date
john;id_123;33;A;2023-03-29
john;id_123;33;B;2023-03-29
peter;id_222;55;A;2023-03-30
peter;id_222;44;B;2023-03-30
mary;id_333;88;A;2023-30-30
```

I would like to filter out some results, and create 3 new datasets.

1.Remove duplicates, from different sources. If there is a multiple record for the same ID, with the same date, leave only the record of the source B. Create new DF based on this filtering. New DF should look like this

```
 name;id;value;source;date
 john;id_123;33;B;2023-03-29
 peter;id_222;44;B;2023-03-30
 mary;id_333;88;A;2023-30-30
```

2.Example of John: Remove duplicates, from different sources. If there is a same ID, with same value and same date, but different source, I would like to drop source A, and just leave the row with source B. Then create new DF that would contain all original records, minus "john like" records with source A. New DF should look like this:

```
name;id;value;source;date
john;id_123;33;B;2023-03-29
peter;id_222;55;A;2023-03-30
peter;id_222;44;B;2023-03-30
mary;id_333;88;A;2023-30-30
```

3.Example of Peter: find all records with following conditions: same ID, same date, different values. Keep both records. Find all of those cases and create a new DF from it.
New DF should look like this:

```
name;id;value;source;date
peter;id_222;55;A;2023-03-30
peter;id_222;44;B;2023-03-30
```

Comment: input must be provided as text to be copied. plz do not provide images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: How to filter dataframe for duplicate items that occur at least n times in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918506/pandas-how-to-filter-dataframe-for-duplicate-items-that-occur-at-least-n-times)

Comment: Hi have you checked this [how to provide a minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try looking at [Pandas Drop Duplicate Rows - drop_duplicates() function](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/pandas-drop-duplicate-rows-drop_duplicates-function#4-identify-duplicate-rows-based-on-specific-columns).

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: OK. Don't worry I'll solve this problem for you

Comment: @botafogo why didn't the suggested questions/answers solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**

If there is a multiple record for the same ID, with the same date, leave only the record of the source B

```
cond1 = df.duplicated(['id', 'date'], keep=False)
cond2 = df['source'].ne('B')
df[~(cond1 & cond2)]
```

output:

```
    name    id      value   source  date
1   john    id_123  33      B       2023-03-29
3   peter   id_222  44      B       2023-03-30
4   mary    id_333  88      A       2023-30-30
```

**2**

If there is a same ID, with same value and same date, but different source,  just leave the row with source B.

```
cond3 = df.duplicated(['id', 'value', 'date'], keep=False)
df[~(cond3 & cond2)]
```

output

```
    name    id      value   source  date
1   john    id_123  33      B       2023-03-29
2   peter   id_222  55      A       2023-03-30
3   peter   id_222  44      B       2023-03-30
4   mary    id_333  88      A       2023-30-30
```

**3**

same ID, same date, different values. Keep both records.

```
df[cond1 & ~cond3]
```

output:

```
    name    id      value   source  date
2   peter   id_222  55      A       2023-03-30
3   peter   id_222  44      B       2023-03-30
```